# Not able to log in to docker hub from terminal

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to login to docker hub from terminal. But I am not able to login. Following are the set of commands and the error:

```
docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: username
Password: ********

Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Service Unavailable
```

Also when I am trying to run the dockerfile using `docker build .` command, I am getting the same error. I am using MacOS. I tried searching about this but had no luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any proxy or are you behind any corporate network ?

Comment: Yes, I am in a corporate network. How can I change that.

Comment: usually there is poxy configured to connect to the internet. If that is not configured you can switch the network to your personal one and re-try. Also check the password is working when logged in via the browser.

Comment: I added `{ "insecure-registries" : ["https://name-of-my-registry:5000"] }` to file  `/etc/docker/daemon.json` on my local machine and executed `sudo systemctl restart docker`.